# PyQt. Highliting some places in text using QSyntaxHighlighter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have had a program in PyQt5. The program have had a QTextEdit field for printing clear HTML using Python’s method html.escape(). Every string have added in the field using .append(). Some tags in some strings needed to be highlighted. And I have used next code:

```
self.textEdit.append('{0}{color}{1}{endcolor}{2}'.format(begin,
color_text, end, color='<font color="red">', endcolor='</font>')
```

Lately I found a module in Internet that can print strings number. This module use QPlainTextEdit. Also I found a module for syntax highlight, that was arranged by QSyntaxHighlighter and it’s for QPlainTextEdit too. It all works good, but now I can‘t highlight additional tags using code above. I have to highlight not only html syntax, but also additional some tags by other color. I tried to create another QSyntaxHighlighter that would highlight a whole text it get.

```
def format(color, style=''):
    _color = QColor()
    _color.setNamedColor(color)
    _format = QTextCharFormat()
    _format.setForeground(_color)
    return _format

class PythonHighlighter (QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, document):
       QSyntaxHighlighter.__init__(self, document)

    def highlightBlock(self, text):
        self.setFormat(0, len(text), format('red'))
        self.setCurrentBlockState(0)
```

Then in necessary place I write:

```
highlight = syntax.PythonHighlighter(self.textEdit.document())
self.textEdit.show()
self.textEdit.appendPlainText(...)
```

I thought to apply this highlighter to places of html that between{color} and {endcolor} above in code. Can I apply highlighter only to part of field? How? And if I can't, which are there methods to solve my problem?
P.S. Sorry for mistakes in my English. You can tell me about them.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you must provide a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Do you think that with this code we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @eyllanesc Done

Comment: What kind of text do you want to highlight, do they have some pattern? What is the style in format?

Comment: @eyllanesc html have many tags, that have syntax highlight. Program have to process it and additionally highlight some tags yet. For example, syntax highlighter highlight all tags <div>, <a>,<p>, etc using blue color. But it needs to highlight tag <div> in string 5 column 15 using grey color and tag <a> in 55 string, 28 column using red color. That's way this tag have no patterns and don't differ from another such tags.

Comment: You could put some of those rules in your question

Comment: @eyllanesc I gave an example. Program solve which tags needs to be highlighted using long algorithm. There are no any rules that I can introduce into highlighter.

Comment: Then you have the algorithm that makes the match. I am right?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, I have long algorythm, program run it and result is a list of tags with numbers of strings and columns.

Comment: If you know when the position and length of each pattern begins, why do not you just use `self.setFormat(start_of_match, length_of_match, some_format)`?

Comment: I want to do so. But then I must have second QSyntaxHighlighter. One for all QPlainTextEdit and another for this parts of text. It is possible?

Comment: You can not add that, you do not have to create another QSyntaxHighlighter, just add those rules inside that class and invoke them in highlightBlock.

Comment: But if it needs to highlight div in string 5, column 15, how can I add string number in highlightBlock? Which will be .setFormat()?

Comment: You have to convert the string number and the column in the position and length of the string with respect to the document.

Comment: `self.setFormat(posittion_of_the_string_respect_to_the_document, length_of_string, some_format)`

Comment: That is to highlight div in string 5, column 15, I have to add together lengths 1, 2, 3, 4 strings, add 5. That will be "posittion_of_the_string_respect_to_the_docume‌​nt". Then add one self.setFormat yet for next tag?

Comment: You could share your project to help you, I think you are not understanding me

Comment: @eyllanesc I didn't understood. What 'string respect to the docume‌​nt' is meaning? For example, I have a list with numbers of strings and columns `numbers`: [(5,15),(8,18)]. What can I do after?  `for num in numbers: self.setFormat(begin, end, format('red'))`. What should to be instead of begin, end?

Comment: Let's say that in the first row is the phrase "Hello World", in the second "Good Bye", then the position of Bye is 11 + 5 (Hello 5, space 1, World 5, Good 4, and 1 space)

Comment: @eyllanesc It doesn't work so. I tryed. .setFormat try to apply format to every string. If I write `self.setFormat(16, 18, format('red'))` QSyntaxHighlight colored symbols in every string from 16 to 18 even if string shorter

Comment: That position is with respect to the document, that is to say to the whole text, it is not only the new text, I have tested it and it works correctly. :P

Comment: see this example: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/9afede5ccad0183b0950d27273dbdc5e

Comment: @eyllanesc How??? See. I write: `highlight = PythonHighlighter(self.textEdit.document()); self.create_widget.textEdit.show(); self.create_widget.textEdit.setPlainText(text)`; in highlightBlock: `for num in numbers: self.setFormat(num[0], num[1], format_all('red'))`, where numbers is list turples, that has number of strings and columns, counted from begin of document. It does not work. It highlight this places on every string.

Comment: You have seen that my code works, something you have done wrong, if I do not have your code, I will not be able to help you unfortunately, since a few comments I am redoing the same thing and I am getting bored. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc Stop bored) Your code doesn't work. You code has QTextEdit field and html text is printing on one string: https://yadi.sk/i/3vWXMSaP3PCs8A It's working. But if I'll change field: `w = QPlainTextEdit(); w.setPlainText(text)` text is printing on a few strings (that's what I need) and it's doesn't work: https://yadi.sk/i/PnnvJHek3PCs8H

Comment: Without code I will not help you, I do not want to waste my time anymore.

Comment: QPlainTextEdit is different to QTextEdit. What are you using?

Comment: I am using QPlainTextEdit

Comment: As I said, if you want to help me share the code. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc This is a part of my project https://gist.github.com/serkomma/b2a39ed98d74d7d8a6504e3fd5c321fa